# JavaAgent" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.bea.domingo.DNotesFactory

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I'm try debuging the follownig java agent in domino designer

```
  public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
     public void NotesMain() {
     DNotesFactory factory = DNotesFactory.getInstance();
        DSession session = factory.getSession();
        DDatabase database;
        try {
            database = session.getDatabase("", "names.nsf");
            DView view = database.getView("($Users)");
            Iterator entries = view.getAllEntries();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                DViewEntry entry = (DViewEntry) entries.next();
                System.out.println(entry.getColumnValues().get(0));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }             
    }
  }
```

but I get the following exception

```
JavaAgent" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.bea.domingo.DNotesFactory
```

Comment: make sure you add the path to the file domingo-1.x.jar to the JavaUserClasses variable in your notes.ini file. the exception simply means that DNotesFactory cannot be found in the classpath. More detailed explanation on this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: I added this jar to class path,but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is a **runtime error**. That means, that `domingo-1.5.1.jar` is available in Designer during editing and saving Java agent and the code could be compiled.

So, the jar file is not available at runtime.

There are three ways to store **jar** files for **Java agents** so that they are available at runtime:

1. in directory ...\Lotus\Notes\jvm\lib\ext
2. in agent's Archive part
3. in Java Library's Archive part

Be aware that jar files in Code/Jars are ignored for Java agents (they can only be used by XPages).

### 1.

Copy the **jar** file to directory ...\Lotus\Notes\**jvm\lib\ext**. Restart the Notes client. Your Java agent will run on Notes client then.

### 2.

Add the **jar** file with Import/Archive to Java agent itself:

[image]

### 3.

If you have several agents using the **jar** file then you should create a Java library with the jar file and include the library to the agents:

[image]

---

From your other questions I can see that you are working with Notes Domino version 9. The project domingo is pretty much out of date and doesn't support all new functionalities. Use  OpenNTF Domino API **org.openntf.domino** instead. A description how to use this API with Java agents you can find [here](https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/wiki/Using-the-API:-Agents). The places where to store jar files for Java agents are always the same though.

Comment: All of images are not shown here :( If The nsf file is on server What then? Should i put the same jar file in to Domino Server *jvm\lib\ext ?

Comment: Yes, if you go with approach #1. No, for approaches #2 and #3 as they keep the jars inside nsf.

Comment: What do you mean by "All of images are not shown here :( " - I can see all images in my answer...

Comment: You can but I cannot :(( Sorry I added my Question What i mean :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the domingo classes, you need to add this:

```
import  de.bea.domingo.*;
```

You might also want to consider using the new [OpenNTF Domino API classes](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API) instead of the domingo classes. The OpenNTF project is newer and more ambitious, and they are actively improving their code.